# Can't create new project from existing in PHPStorm

Tags: project, phpstorm

I just installed PHPStorm 6.0.3 on my mac (Lion 10.7.5).  I successfully added one project via New Project From Existing (SFTP), but when I try to add a second New Project From Existing (also SFTP), it looks like it starts the download process and then stops without any warning.  Any clues?

TIA!

**UPDATE**

I noticed that PHPStorm kept closing the download when it came to a particular directory.  By setting the directory to be excluded from download, the project was successfully downloaded.

**SECOND UPDATE**

Upon further inspection of the 'bad' directory, I noticed that someone had added circular links to it.  It could be that PHPStorm caught an error and failed silently when it came across those bad links.

Comment: Check the logs? `Help (or whatever it is called on Mac) | Show Log in Finder`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to fix (remove circular links) or exclude the directory from which the download was failing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to create a project from existing files, but the directory was already a project.

So the error is a not well expressed.

If this happens to you open the project instead of creating a new one